# SQL QUERY to display List of User who does not have any kind of transactions since last 6 months

Tags: sql, oracle10g

pl help me to get List of User who does not have any kind of transactions since last 6 months

I tried with below Query, Still list of ID getting display who have current Transaction too,but i want details of thise CLients who is inactive for last 6 months, ie. no transactions since last 6 months

```
select AST_ID,
AST_VALUE_DATE,
max(distinct(AST_VALUE_DATE)) from account_statement 

having max(AST_VALUE_DATE)<='30-09-2020'   
group by AST_ID,
AST_VALUE_DATE
order by AST_VALUE_DATE desc;
```

Can anybody help where am i getting wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful to include your table structure (so we can see the data types), sample data and expected results for that data, along with the incorrect results you get with your query and why they are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply want:

```
select AST_ID, max(LAST_VALUE_DATE) as LAST_VALUE_DATE
from account_statement 
group by AST_ID
having max(LAST_VALUE_DATE) <= DATE '2020-09-30'
order by LAST_VALUE_DATE desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but with above mentioned query ,  i am still getting those Client data who transaction happened  after "2020-09-30" , i just wanted a list of those Clients whose Last transactions must be less than or equal to 2020-09-30

Comment: @ArvikS - I don't see how... unless `AST_VALUE_DATE` is a string, not a real date?

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by the ID and the date; the `max(AST_VALUE_DATE)` is always going to be the same as the `AST_VALUE_DATE` for every row. (The distinct isn't adding anything).

You are also comparing against a string, not a date; which is relying on implicit conversion.

Remove the extra `AST_VALUE_DATE` from the select list and group-by, and compare with a proper date, either as a literal:

```
select AST_ID, max(AST_VALUE_DATE) as AST_VALUE_DATE
from account_statement 
group by AST_ID
having max(AST_VALUE_DATE) < date '2020-09-30'
order by AST_VALUE_DATE desc;
```

or by looking back six months from today:

```
having max(AST_VALUE_DATE) < add_months(trunc(sysdate), -6)
```

or by looking back six months from the start of the current month:

```
having max(AST_VALUE_DATE) < add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -6)
```

which I imagine is what you want based on your current string value.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce57f2b0a5c00bbf309707ca94dd10d9)